# Page_Load is called when leaving page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, master-pages

I have a master page and two web pages, WebForm1 and WebForm2. On the master page there are two LinkButtons in order to go to WebForm1 or WebForm2.

When I click on the LinkButton to go to WebForm1 the Page_Load event handler for WebForm1 is called and Page.IsPostBack == false. So far so good.

Then when I click to go to WebForm2 this happens:

```
a) The Page_Load event handler for WebForm1 is called again and Page.IsPostBack == true.
b) Then the Page_Load event handler for WebForm2 is called and its Page_Load == false.

Vice versa when going back to WebForm1.
```

Why is Page_Load for WebForm1 called when I'm going to WebForm2? I am loading WebForm2 and not WebForm1.

For all pages: AutoEventWireup="true".

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <p>This is MySite.Master.</p>
    <p>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="goto1" runat="server" OnClick="goto1_Click">Go To WebForm1</asp:LinkButton>
    </p>
    <p>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="goto2" runat="server" OnClick="goto2_Click">Go To WebForm2</asp:LinkButton>
    </p>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>


protected void goto1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx");
}

protected void goto2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");
}



public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        if (Page.IsPostBack) {

        }
    }
}



public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        if (Page.IsPostBack) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is the way asp.net buttons work. They cause a page postback, which is why page_load is hit again. THEN the click handler will fire.

Comment: @S.Akbari please see answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add on to Kirk's answer...

When you just want a simple link to another page, don't use `LinkButton` at all. `LinkButton` is just a submit button, which is designed to look like a link - it's all hooked up magically through javascript that ASP.NET builds automatically.

If you want a link to simply send you to another page, just do it in regular HTML:

```
<a href="WebForm2.aspx">Go To WebForm2</a>
```

Comment: I tried <a href... and it does exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

What you are seeing is that clicking on `goto1` or `goto2` is causing the page to do a *Postback* which follows the page lifecycle. In this case it involves both the masterpage and the content page.

A couple links that are useful for this are

[ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

[MasterPage and Content Page life cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3.aspx)

In particular with the masterpage involved, these are the order of events

> 1. Content page **PreInit** event.
> 2. Master page controls **Init** event.
> 3. Content controls **Init** event.
> 4. Master page **Init** event.
> 5. Content page **Init** event.
> 6. Content page **Load** event.
> 7. Master page **Load** event.
> 8. Master page controls **Load** event.
> 9. Content page controls **Load** event.
> 10. Content page **PreRender** event.
> 11. Master page **PreRender** event.
> 12. Master page controls **PreRender** event.
> 13. Content page controls **PreRender** event.
> 14. Master page controls **Unload** event.
> 15. Content page controls **Unload** event.
> 16. Master page **Unload** event.
> 17. Content page **Unload** event.

These happen on a *PostBack* and you will see a

> Content page **Load** event

which is why your `Page_Load` event is firing for the `Click` event causing a *PostBack* and the full life cycle is executed for *WebForm1* before

```
Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");
```

executes.